# How to configure Nginx to Configure Vhost for subdomain to a proxypass matching

Tags: nginx

I am trying to achieve is

if a user hits  user1.example.com  then the nginx should show the content of app at http://127.0.0.1:3001/user1

similarly for  user2.example.com  then the nginx should show the content of app at http://127.0.0.1:3001/user2

How should I configure the vhost block ?

Current configuration is

server {
    listen 80;

```
server_name user1.example.com ;
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/user1;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

}

and similar blocks for other user too, The problem I am getting is for any block which is not defined the  like say if user3.example.com  block is not defined, the first block is used . I want  to set a default block for non defined routes, how could I do that ?

Also, I am making the server blocks through scripts  dynamically on demand and reloading the server .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a block for every user why don't you do it dynamically.

```
server {
    server_name     ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.example\.com$;
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3001/$subdomain ;
    }
}
```

So when you hit: 
user1.example.com => http://127.0.0.1:3001/user1